# Using lessc on Windows

Tags: less, therubyracer

I've been trying to work out how to install lesscss.org on Windows 7 so I can use it from a cygwin command line interface and also using Maven.

We have SASS running in this way but there is a requirement to use LESS in a new project.

My Steps so far...

1. Checked Ruby is installed, I have it installed at C:\Ruby193
2. Downloaded [the Ruby DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) and followed this to install it.
3. At CMD.exe, execute `gem install less` - 1 gem installed ... less-2.2.1
4. CMD.exe, run `lessc` - This gives [WARNING] Please install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less.
5. So at CMD.exe I try `gem install therubyracer` which gives this error...

ERROR:

> Error installing therubyracer: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Full error is [here](http://pastebin.com/f1pUjXYn)

6. And this is where I'm stuck because `lessc` is still complaining therubyracer is not installed. I've also installed Python27 and added it to the Path variable as that came up in a previous error.

I can confirm I have this path `C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\therubyracer-0.10.1` which looks like a project to me but something is obviously wrong.

I've also found this as a potential answer to getting LESS on Windows but that would indicate we can't get the native 'real' version to run so both Macs, Windows and Ubuntu can use the same switches/ environment? github.com/duncansmart/less.js-windows

Comment: Less is now JavaScript, not ruby and runs in node on any os.

Comment: OK cool, I installed Node last week whilst trying allto get this working - How do I run Less through node? I've opened the Node.JS command prompt, typed `lessc` but it doesn't recognise it...

I'm guessing once this is done, i can run Less through Node through a Maven project... Thanks.

Comment: apparantly you just do "npm install less"? Not sure.

Comment: It says it comes with a binary lessc but its just a javascript file, so if you set up node to run it and then pass in arguments for your less files, it might just work..

Comment: Mmm, ok sounds like I need to do some digging. I've never used Node... Was hoping for a hand holding guided tour on this :)

Comment: Sorry! Thats why its a comment not an answer...

Answer (score 8):

As the others mentioned, this is now easily done with node:

`npm install -g less`

This will install less as a global module that you can use from anywhere on the command line by typing:

`lessc input-file.less output-file.css`

An even easer way to do this is to just use a tool like SimpleLess that will automagically compile and minify your LESS for you:

http://wearekiss.com/simpless

Happy Coding!

Comment: The Url link you provided no longer provides the SimpleLess tool. In fact, has no content.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you had the same problem I did where you successfully installed the node module via:

```
npm install -g less
```

but when trying to run lessc, you were getting the error:

```
[WARNING] Please install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less.
```

I think this is because, though you've installed the node module, the lessc command is still tied to the ruby gem. Try uninstalling the less gem:

```
gem uninstall less
```

And then try running lessc again.